# Orphan planet life plausibility

Tags: environment, flora, ecology, radiation

Some say life could exist on an orphan planet by using radiation like plants use sunlight. This seems plausible since some fungi do the same. But how much natural radioactive material could realistically be on a rocky planet? Does this make a transuranic based ecosystem plausible?

Comment: When you say radiation, what do you mean? IR radiation (heat) or radioactivity. I've never heard of any fungus that uses radioactivity for a power source.

Comment: @NomadMaker https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiotrophic_fungus

Comment: Since the orphan planet will probably not be moving very fast, it may have cooled off quite a bit.

Comment: @Joe Smith What do you mean by an "orphan planet"?  Do you mean a "rogue planet" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet?  There is a theory that a rogue planet might still be warm enough. And also a rouge Jupiter like planet with large moons like the Galilean moons may have an Io analog that is supervolcanic due to tidal interactions with the planet tand the other moons.  A moon large enough to be habitable, and with strong tidal heating, but less than Io's, might be warm enough for life. https://faculty.washington.edu/rkb9/publications/hb13.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of [radiotrophic fungi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiotrophic_fungus). The problem with those is that they need a significant flux of suitable radiation in order to provide them with energy, and although the Earth has a significant amount of radioactives in it, they're reasonably well dispersed and so background radiation levels just aren't very high.

[Natural nuclear reactors have existed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor), but their power output is low and they didn't last for a particularly long period of time, and could only exist on a young world where there's a decent inventory of convenient fissiles.

> Does this make a transuranic based ecosystem plausible?

Not even slightly. Transuranics are *rare*. They can only be generated naturally in supernovae, and by the very nature of those supernovae the relatively small amount of heavy elements they create will be scattered far and wide over literally astronomical distances, and will be mixed in with a far greater proportion of stable lighter elements.

Thus you end up with L.Dutch's solution; an ecosystem driven by geothermal heat generated by the decay of radioisotopes in the mantle and core.

Note that this primordial heat source is rather limited compared to heat from the sun... it has been estimated at about [3% of the energy received from the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_internal_heat_budget). Any ecosystems that rely on it will be found deep down, under thick layers of insulating rock and ice because the surface of the world is likely to be close to the cosmic background temperature of 2.7K. [Sedna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90377_Sedna), which still orbits a star albeit at a great distance, has a surface temperature of 12K.

Because of this, you're only likely to find complex multicellular life in deep oceans that remain liquid... forget underdark-like visions of vast fungus-filled caverns with cave dwelling species. There won't be a sufficiently active hydrosphere to form big caves via flowing water (no rain, you see) and lithostatic pressure, earthquakes and volcanism and so on will act to close up any large voids over relatively short periods of time, geologically and evolutionarily speaking.

So, yeah. TL;DR: what L.Dutch said. But now you know why ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Black smokers and white smokers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent#Black_smokers_and_white_smokers) on Earth are the closest examples of how life could look like on a rogue planet unbound to a star

> Life has traditionally been seen as driven by energy from the sun, but deep-sea organisms have no access to sunlight, so biological communities around hydrothermal vents must depend on nutrients found in the dusty chemical deposits and hydrothermal fluids in which they live. Previously, Benthic oceanographers assumed that vent organisms were dependent on marine snow, as deep-sea organisms are. This would leave them dependent on plant life and thus the sun. Some hydrothermal vent organisms do consume this "rain", but with only such a system, life forms would be sparse. Compared to the surrounding sea floor, however, hydrothermal vent zones have a density of organisms 10,000 to 100,000 times greater.
>
> The hydrothermal vents are recognized as a type of chemosynthetic based ecosystems (CBE) where primary productivity is fuelled by chemical compounds as energy sources instead of light (chemoautotrophy). Hydrothermal vent communities are able to sustain such vast amounts of life because vent organisms depend on chemosynthetic bacteria for food. The water from the hydrothermal vent is rich in dissolved minerals and supports a large population of chemoautotrophic bacteria. These bacteria use sulfur compounds, particularly hydrogen sulfide, a chemical highly toxic to most known organisms, to produce organic material through the process of chemosynthesis.

To feed them apparently it's sufficient the heat produced by the concentration of radioactive material we have in our planet, not exceptionally high.

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask what Joe Smith means by an "orphan planet".

My best guess is that he means a "rogue planet".

> A rogue planet (also termed an interstellar, nomad, free-floating, unbound, orphan, wandering, starless, or sunless planet) is a planetary-mass object that does not orbit a star directly. Such objects have been ejected from the planetary system in which they formed or have never been gravitationally bound to any star or brown dwarf.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet#Sunless,_yet_warm)[2](https://www.nature.com/articles/21811) The Milky Way alone may have billions to trillions of rogue planets, a range which the upcoming Nancy Grace Roman Space Telescope will likely be able to narrow down.[4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.0945.pdf)
>
> Some planetary-mass objects may have formed in a similar way to stars, and the International Astronomical Union has proposed that such objects be called sub-brown dwarfs.[6] A possible example is Cha 110913-773444, which may have been ejected and become a rogue planet, or formed on its own to become a sub-brown dwarf.[7]

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet%5B3%5D)

We would expect that the majority of rogue planets would have surface temperatures similar to those of interstellar space - only a little above absolute zero - since they would receive only about as much energy from distant stars as starlight on Earth.

> Sunless, yet warm
>
> Interstellar planets generate little heat and are not heated by a star.[22] However, in 1998, David J. Stevenson theorized that some planet-sized objects adrift in interstellar space might sustain a thick atmosphere that would not freeze out. He proposed that these atmospheres would be preserved by the pressure-induced far-infrared radiation opacity of a thick hydrogen-containing atmosphere.[23]
>
> During planetary-system formation, several small protoplanetary bodies may be ejected from the system.[24] An ejected body would receive less of the stellar-generated ultraviolet light that can strip away the lighter elements of its atmosphere. Even an Earth-sized body would have enough gravity to prevent the escape of the hydrogen and helium in its atmosphere.[23] In an Earth-sized object that has a kilobar atmospheric pressure of hydrogen and a convective gas adiabat[clarification needed], the geothermal energy from residual core radioisotope decay could maintain a surface temperature above the melting point of water,[23] allowing liquid-water oceans to exist. These planets are likely to remain geologically active for long periods. If they have geodynamo-created protective magnetospheres and sea floor volcanism, hydrothermal vents could provide energy for life.[23] These bodies would be difficult to detect because of their weak thermal microwave radiation emissions, although reflected solar radiation and far-infrared thermal emissions may be detectable from an object that is less than 1000 astronomical units from Earth.[25] Around five percent of Earth-sized ejected planets with Moon-sized natural satellites would retain their satellites after ejection. A large satellite would be a source of significant geological tidal heating.[26]

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet#Sunless,_yet_warm[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet#Sunless,_yet_warm%5B1%5D)

[https://www.nature.com/articles/21811[2]](https://www.nature.com/articles/21811%5B2%5D)

[https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.1108.pdf[4]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.1108.pdf%5B4%5D)

[https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.0945.pdf[5]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.0945.pdf%5B5%5D)

And what if a gas giant planet is ejected from a star system along with its moons, some of which might be very large.  Tidal interactions between the planet and its moons may cause significant tidal heating

Io, the innermost large moon of Jupiter, is very volcnically active, way too active for life to flourish even if Io was otherwise perfectly suited for life.

In the article "Exomoon Habitability Constrained by Illumination and Tidal Heating" Rene Heller and Roy Barnes, *Astrobiology*, Volume 13, issue 1, 2013, the conditions necessary for exomoons of exoplanets in other star systems to be habitable are discussed.  Their discussson mostly involves hypothetical exomoons orbiting exoplanets in the circumstellar habitable zones of their stars, where the exoplanets and their exomoons receive enough radiation from their stars to have the right temperature range for liquid water.  but their conclusions could be modified for exomoons orbiting farther out from their stars, or even for rogue exoplanets with their exommons orbiting in interstellar space.

In that article Heller and Barnes introduce the concept of the "habitable edge" a distance of an exomoon from its exoplanet where the combined energy from the star and from tidal heating would created a runaway greenhouse effect, such as the one suffered by Venus, and make the exomoon too hot to be habitable.

In section 2.3 *Runaway greenhouse* they discuss the dangers of a runaway greenhouse effect if an exomoon has too much tidal heating.

In section 4. *Orbits of Habitable Exomoons*, they write:

> By analogy with the circumstellar habitable zone for
> planets, we can imagine a minimum orbital separation between a planet and a moon to let the satellite be habitable.
> The range of orbits for habitable moons has no outer edge,
> except that Hill stability must be ensured. Consequently,
> habitability of moons is only constrained by the inner edge of
> a circumplanetary habitable zone, which we call the ‘‘habitable edge.’’ Moons inside the habitable edge are in danger
> of running into a greenhouse by stellar and planetary illumination and/or tidal heating. Satellites outside the habitable edge with their host planet in the circumstellar IHZ are
> habitable by definition.

So a large exomoon orbiting a giant exoplanet in the circumstellar habitable zone of their star would receive too much internal and external heat and light and would suffer a runaway greenhouse effect if it orbited the planet within the habitable edge of that planet.

Thus I deduce that if the exoplanet and exomoon are moved farther and farther away from the circumstellar habitable zone of their star, the exomoon would need to be closer and closer to the habitable edge so that the heat from the star that it doesn't get will be replaced by more and more tidal heating.  And thehabitable edge of the exoplanet would probably more closer and closer to the planet as the heat contribution from the star got less and less.

Thus I think that it is possible for a exomoon orbiting a giant rogue planet in interstellar space to be heated up enough to have liquid water on its surface.

Maybe that liquid water will be in a subsurface ocean beneath an insulating ice layer many miles thick.

But if the exomoon is large enough to have an atmosphere many times denser than Earth's and containing a lot of hydrogen, that atmosphere may act as a sufficient insulating layer to keep the exomoon's land and ocean surfaces  war enoough for life.

I note that it might be possible for some life forms on any hypothetical rogue planet or moon - that may be  warm enough for liguid water - to develope photosynthesis.  The light for photosynthesis may come from numerous volcanic eruptions, and depending on the meteorology of the world's atmosphere, from constant lightening.

One way to increase natural radiation for the equivalent of radiotrophic fungi is for the rough planet or moon to encounter a rogue asteroid from a much younger star system, where heavy elements have not yet decayed and are more abundant.

Any PMO or planetary mass object would have a core, a mantle, and a crust, with the heavier elemens closer to the center.  If that PMO collides with another object, it might be shatter into many pieces, some from the core some from the mantle, and some from the crust.  That is the process which produced iron nickel asteroids in our solar system.

Just as planets can be ejected by gravitational interactions from their star systems and become rogue planets, moons, comets, and asteroids can be ejected from their star systems and wander in interstellar space.  That includes asteroids which are fragments the cores of planetary mass objects and are mostlycomposed of heavy elements which include radioactive isotropes.

And maybe some of those hypothetical young core fragments might encounter lone rogue planets or a rogue planet with a system of moons.  And if the distances, directions of travel, and speed differences are just right, the young core fragment might be captured byrouge pane tor planet with moons.

I believe the most likely method of that capture would be if the core fragment encountered two or more bodies and one of the other bodies of similar mass was ejected from the system as the core fragment was captured.  And then if the core fragment orbits in the system of a planet's moons, it might collide with a similar size moon of that planet and produce a ring of fragments, fragments which a hypothetical habitable moonof that planet might sweep up.  Thus the surface of the hypothetical habitable moon might gain a lot of radioactive materials from the core fragment that would increase theenergy supply for any radiotropic life forms it might have..

Answer (score 0):

**Decently plausible**.  First, life doesn't need to cower around black smokers underground.  If the planet is warm and can radiate to space, then there is actually such a thing as "[anti-solar cells](https://www.ucdavis.edu/news/anti-solar-cells-photovoltaic-cell-works-night)"!  Instead of tapping energy on the way in, tap it on the way out.  With the same trees and grasses you would have on a planet with light!

Of course, you can have communities that tap the heat differential where it is released also.  Anti-solar cells could work there also, at a higher frequency, or they could rely on conversion of inorganic chemicals in a planetary cycle.  (Some chemicals are more stable at high temperatures but can be reacted to other chemicals to produce energy at low temperatures)

Now about the radioactive isotopes - current thinking typically favors [neutron star mergers](https://phys.org/news/2019-11-alchemy-merging-neutron-stars.html) though supernovae are certainly not out of the running.  These are occasional rare events and it is unlikely that Earth got the most radioactive material possible.  Even Earth had a [natural nuclear reactor in Gabon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor), but another planet could have this occur more often.

That said, you don't need to rely just on radiation - tidal interactions with a close, large moon (or a larger planet your moon revolves around) can provide lots of heat energy for a fairly long time.